# ¿Cómo insertar varias calificaciones a varios alumnos?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

Tengo la siguiente pantalla, donde se muestran unos campos y una tabla, necesito guardar los datos: id_grupo, id_clase, id_alumno y par1. ¿Qué tengo que hacer para que cada alumno tenga esos datos?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
include("conexion.php");
$con=conectar();




$alumno=$_POST['alumno'];
$clase=$_POST['id_clase'];
$periodo=$_POST['periodo_id'];
$par=$_POST['par1'];

for( $i = 0; $i < count($alumno); $i++ ){
  $alu = $alumno[$i];
  $cla = $clase[$i];
  $per = $periodo[$i];
  $pa = $par[$i];
  //Ya puedes hacer tu query, sería masomenos así
  $sql = "INSERT INTO calificaciones(id_alumno, id_periodo, id_clase, calificacion) VALUES($alu, $cla, $per,$pa)";
}


$query=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

?>
```

Comment: El código va _como texto, con formato_. Lee [ask].

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, revisa [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) dinos que has investigado y los inconvenientes que tuviste cuando intentaste solucionar tu problema. Necesitas crear un [ejemplo mínimo verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de esta forma indicas que formas parte de los que intentan solucionar tu problema.

Answer (score 0):

bienvenido.
Tené en cuenta que en tu código tenés lo siguiente:

```
for( $i = 0; $i < count($alumno); $i++ ){
  $alu = $alumno[$i];
  $cla = $clase[$i];
  $per = $periodo[$i];
  $pa = $par[$i];
  //Ya puedes hacer tu query, sería masomenos así
  $sql = "INSERT INTO calificaciones(id_alumno, id_periodo, id_clase, calificacion) VALUES($alu, $cla, $per,$pa)";
}
```

Sin embargo, la clase y el período se envían una sola vez, por lo que si hacés:

```
$clase[$i]
```

Cuando `$i` vale `0` funciona bien, pero cuando `$i` vale más te va a dar nulo o error por overflow. Tené en cuenta que al estar dentro de un bucle `for`, el valor se va incrementando en cada ciclo.

Por lo que si solo envías esos datos una sola vez, debes sacarlos fuera del bucle. Sería algo así:

```
//Datos fijos
$clase=$_POST['periodo_id'];
$periodo=$_POST['id_clase'];
//Array
$alumno=$_POST['alumno'];
$par=$_POST['par1'];

for( $i = 0; $i < count($alumno); $i++ ){
  $alu = $alumno[$i];
  $pa = $par[$i];

  $sql = "INSERT INTO calificaciones(id_alumno, id_periodo, id_clase, calificacion) VALUES($alu, $clase, $periodo,$pa)";
}
```

Te recomiendo que leas, además, cómo hacer los insert con el comando `bindParam`. Te va a ayudar en un futuro a que tu sistema sea más seguro.